# How can I make a countdown timer in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

How can I make a countdown timer in PHP which starts at 40 seconds and counts in this format:

> 40.59 - 40.48 - 40.47 - etc etc

I also need a button that resets it.

Is this possible in PHP? Do I need to use JavaScript?

Comment: You should look into javascript NOT java or PHP.

Comment: Why is everyone saying JS? Because to see the timer go down in PHP you would have to refresh the page every second. JS does that in real-time without refreshing

Answer (score 3):

You will need JavaScript to achieve a timer.

Some useful resources:

http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=61593

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/JavaScript/Using-Timers-in-JavaScript/

Answer (score 2):

You would do this entirely on the client side using Java**script**, there are many examples if you google for *javascript countdown*, ex http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html.

Comment: Not sure why someone voted this down. seems to be a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is executed server side; You'll need to use JavaScript or some other client-side language (flash, silverlight, java applet, etc) if you want it displayed to a user in real-time.